# Select all the characters that have items on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a table on MySQL, called Items with 2 columns: Id and Name. I want to show my items, filtering by its name first character. To do this, now I'm using this query:

```
Select Id,Name from Items WHERE Name LIKE 'a%'
```

I have 2 questions:

1) It is this the best method to achieve that?

2) To create the filter view, I want to know which characters have at least one item name starting with it. For example, I don't have any item name starting with "X". How could I know which ones have with a single query?

Thanks

Comment: `nombre` is a typo, right? Should be `name`.

Comment: Yes, it was! corrected. Thanks juergen. It was the original field name in the query but I translated it when writing the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have an Index on `Name` then your query is fine.
2. To get all characters having Names

   ```
   Select substr(Name, 1, 1) as starting_character
   from Items 
   group by starting_character
   order by starting_character
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could run a large OR query like....

```
 select * from Items where nobre like "A%" or nombre like "B%" or nombre like "C%" //etc etc
```

But if speed and table size is an issue, I would create another column, and just enter the letter value as an INT into that column.  Kinda like an index.

So when you insert any new values, just code up a function to return the letter value of the first letter, and insert that into the new column.

Now you can query the column for any letter, based on that integer.

Hope that came out clearly, Im not very good at explaining things sometimes.....

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the first characters - only once (hence the DISTINCT)

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(Name,1,1) FROM Items ORDER BY SUBSTR(Name,1,1)
```

Then you can use this to create your filters.